# Angular Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'any[]

Tags: angular

Getting the following error. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'any[].  I found similar questions, but I cant figure out how I would apply it to my situation.

Not sure if the mistake is in the OnInIt function or in the line -> @Input() networks = []

//service.ts

```
 @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
 export class NetworkService{

     private networks: Profile[] = [];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

     getNetworks(){
       this.http.get<{message: string, profiles: Profile []}>('http://localhost:3000/api/profiles')
     .subscribe((profileData)=>{
         console.log(profileData)
         this.networks = profileData.profiles;
     });
 }
```

}

//component.ts

```
  export class NetworkComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() networks = [];

    constructor(public networkService: NetworkService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.networks = this.networkService.getNetworks()

   }
```

}

Trying to pass info from the service to the component.  networks = [] should be assigned an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

> Your **service's getNetworks()** should only pass the http call without the subscription since if you subscribe it on your service it will only be accessible within the service but not on the component that you're calling the service to and since you're not returning anything from your getNetworks()

**Service**

If you want to make an explicit return type of getNetworks() you can do so by specifying it: `getNetworks(): Observable<any> {...}` 'any' can be changed to whatever interface you want to assign it based on the return value of your http call

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class NetworkService {

  ...

  getNetworks() {    
     // Add 'return' and let the component subscribe to its response 
     return this.http.get<{message: string, profiles: Profile []}>('http://localhost:3000/api/profiles');
  }
```

**Component**

```
export class NetworkComponent implements OnInit {

   networks: Profile [] = [];

   ...

   ngOnInit() {
      this.networkService
        .getNetworks()
        .subscribe(networks => this.networks = networks.profiles);   // Subscribe and Initialize the networks variable
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got that error is `this.networkService.getNetworks()` returns a void while your `networks` is type of `any[]`

And the pattern of your code is not recommended its better you don't call subscribe on your service instead return the **Observable**

Do it like this

//service.ts

```
 @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
 export class NetworkService{

     // private networks: Profile[] = []; <- this is not needed

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
     // return the Observbale
     getNetworks(){
       return this.http.get<{message: string, profiles: Profile []}>('http://localhost:3000/api/profiles');
 }
```

//component.ts

```
export class NetworkComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() networks = [];

    constructor(public networkService: NetworkService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.networkService.getNetworks()
        .subsribe((res) => { this.networks = res.profiles; });

   }
}
```